# specific country map with district/cities using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to draw some specific countries map such as, **Bangladesh, Bhutan** etc. with its district/cities in R. As an example, I can draw US map using the following lines of codes. Is there any such `library/package` that can give me any countries map with its cities/district/province? Any clue is appreciated.

```
library(maps)
states <- map_data("state")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download shapefile of any country from the following website
https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata
Then read and plot them in R using following code

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

#Reading the shapefiles
sf <- st_read(dsn="C:\\Users\\nn\\Desktop\\BGD_adm", layer="BGD_adm2")
shape <- readOGR(dsn="C:\\Users\\nn\\Desktop\\BGD_adm", layer="BGD_adm2")

#To view the attributes
head(shape@data)
summary(sf)

#Plotting the shapefile
plot(shape)
plot(sf)

#Plotting the districts only
plot(sf["NAME_2"], axes = TRUE, main = "Districts")
```

[image]

```
#Plotting Using ggplot2
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sf, aes(fill = NAME_2)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you @BappaDas, however, using ```ggplot2``` (the second plot) giving me an error ```Error: 'st_normalize' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sf'```, any idea what is the problem in my end?

Comment: Update R to a newer version, and install a newer sf version. Don't forget to accept it as answer to your question by clicking the √ below upvote or downvote button.