# How to import Afghanistan map to R

Tags: r, dictionary, import

I am using Rstudio and would like to import Afghanistan's map with province boundary to R. can anyone help me!

Thanks 
my data structure is:
Province     lat          long              gdp

Comment: I usually download boundary files from gadm.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sp or sf packages.

Download "gadm36_AFG_1_sp.rds" from gadm.org (level 1 = province).

```
AFG_adm1 <- readRDS("gadm36_AFG_1_sp.rds")

library(sp)
op <- par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(AFG_adm1)
```

[image]

You can join this map with your data using the province names (NAME_1).

```
 names(AFG_adm1@data)
 #[1] "GID_0"     "NAME_0"    "GID_1"     "NAME_1"   
 #[5] "VARNAME_1" "NL_NAME_1" "TYPE_1"    "ENGTYPE_1"
 #[9] "CC_1"      "HASC_1"
```

But be careful with the spelling.

```
AFG_adm1$NAME_1
 [1] "Badakhshan" "Badghis"    "Baghlan"    "Balkh"     
 [5] "Bamyan"     "Daykundi"   "Farah"      "Faryab"    
 [9] "Ghazni"     "Ghor"       "Hilmand"    "Hirat"     
[13] "Jawzjan"    "Kabul"      "Kandahar"   "Kapisa"    
[17] "Khost"      "Kunar"      "Kunduz"     "Laghman"   
[21] "Logar"      "Nangarhar"  "Nimroz"     "Nuristan"  
[25] "Paktika"    "Paktya"     "Panjshir"   "Parwan"    
[29] "Samangan"   "Sari Pul"   "Takhar"     "Uruzgan"   
[33] "Wardak"     "Zabul"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the shapefile from https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata.
Then use following code

```
library(rgdal)
df <- readOGR(dsn = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AFG_adm", layer = "AFG_adm2")
#For plotting the map
plot(df)
```

You can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61183368/6123824) for more about plotting shapefile.