# How can I generate a state shapefile and spatial points using levelplot or spplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, levelplot

I have a raster image that I would like to overlay with the state of Hawaii shapefile to provide greater context for the map. Additionally, I'd like to plot specific points on the finished map. Currently, I have a `ggplot` image of the Hawaii shapefile with the points plotted:

```
df <- data.frame(lon, lat)

ggplot(data = world) + geom_sf() + 
       coord_sf(xlim = c(-160, -150), ylim = c(10, 25)) +
       geom_point(data = df, mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat) +
       theme()
```

My raster was constructed using `levelplot`:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package = "raster"))
levelplot(b)
```

When I attempt:

```
> ggplot(data = world) + geom_sf() + coord_sf(xlim = c(-158, -154), ylim = c(17, 24), expand = FALSE) + levelplot(b)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in ggplot(data = world) + geom_sf() + coord_sf(xlim = c(-158, -154),  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "+.trellis") for "+"
```

If these mapping types are incompatible, how can I otherwise generate a Hawaii shapefile with my spatial points via `levelplot` or `spplot`? I realize this data is wacky by using the reproducible Rstudio raster but I wanted to make this question reproducible.

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: You can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182881/specific-country-map-with-district-cities-using-r/61183368#61183368) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175108/add-a-point-on-a-spplot-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the shapefile for Hawaii from [this](http://planning.hawaii.gov/gis/download-gis-data/) site. Then you can plot it using the following code

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

#Reading the shapefiles
sf <- st_read(dsn="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\cty_council_dist.shp", layer="cty_council_dist_haw")
shape <- readOGR(dsn="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\cty_council_dist.shp", layer="cty_council_dist_haw")

#To view the attributes
head(shape@data)
summary(sf)

#Plotting the shapefile
plot(shape)
plot(sf)

#Covert the coordinate system
sf_gcs <- st_transform(sf, crs = "EPSG:4326")
shape_gcs <- spTransform(shape, CRS=CRS("+init=EPSG:4326"))

#Plotting the shapefile
plot(shape)
plot(sf_gcs)

#Plotting the districts only
plot(sf_gcs["cntydist"], axes = TRUE, main = "Districts")
```

[image]
Now to add point data you can use

```
df <- data.frame(lon = c(-155.5, -155.2, -155.3), lat = c(19.2, 19.4, 19.8))
```

As you have not provided the point data, I have created some fake data
#Plotting Using ggplot2

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_sf(data = sf_gcs, aes(fill = cntydist)) + theme(legend.position = "none") +
 geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat), col="green")
```

[image]
**Update**

To plot raster using `ggplot2` you can use the following code

```
#Load the libraries
library(rasterVis)
library(RColorBrewer)

## Create a matrix with random data & use image()
xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
image(xy)

# Turn the matrix into a raster
rast <- raster(xy)

# Give it lat/lon coords for 156.2-154.8°W, 18.5-20.5°N
extent(rast) <- c(-156.2, -154.8, 18.5, 20.5)

#Assign a projection
projection(rast) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
plot(rast)

colr <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'RdYlBu'))

#Plotting Using ggplot2
gplot(rast) +  
  geom_tile(aes(fill=factor(value),alpha=0.8)) + 
  geom_polygon(data=shape_gcs, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
               fill=NA,color="grey50", size=1) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

If you want to plot it using `levelplot` from `rasterVis` package you can use

```
levelplot(rast, 
          margin=F,                       # suppress marginal graphics
          colorkey=list(
            space='right'                   # plot legend at right
          ),    
          par.settings=list(
            axis.line=list(col='transparent') # suppress axes and legend outline
          ),
          scales=list(draw=FALSE),            # suppress axis labels
          col.regions=colr,                   # colour ramp
          at=seq(-5, 5, len=101)) +           # colour ramp breaks
  layer(sp.polygons(shape_gcs, lwd=1))           # add shapefile with latticeExtra::layer
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the links and the detailed response however they don't address my main question. I have a raster that I have plotted with levelplot. ggplot is not compatible with levelplot. I was wondering if I can generate a shapefile using levelplot or spplot.